# On test suite, Google camera stream is skipped, which is not supported

Tags: camera, google-smart-home

On test suite, Google camera stream is skipped, which is not supported. I have realized this function, and I can see camera video on my TV. For example, say to Google, "**Hi Google, show camera on my bed room TV**"

**Like this**

My sync is like this

```
{
    "payload":{
            "agentUserId":"myId",
            "devices":[
                    {
                            "attributes":{
                                    "cameraStreamNeedAuthToken":true,
                                    "cameraStreamNeedDrmEncryption":true,
                                    "cameraStreamSupportedProtocols":[
                                            "hls"
                                    ]
                            },
                            "deviceInfo":{
                                    "hwVersion":"c1",
                                    "manufacturer":"it",
                                    "model":"c12",
                                    "swVersion":"1.3"
                            },
                            "id":"myId",
                            "name":{
                                    "name":"myName"
                            },
                            "traits":[
                                    "action.devices.traits.CameraStream"
                            ],
                            "type":"action.devices.types.CAMERA",
                            "willReportState":true
                    }
            ]
    },
    "requestId":"3339167346796201642"
```

}

Can I help you, brother? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**CameraStream** currently isn’t supported by Test Suite. If you’re trying to [Submit test results](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/tools/smart-home-test-suite#submit_test_results) to [Launch your smart home Action](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/launching), feel free to submit them even if no 100% passed since **CameraStream** is required to pass manual testing by our certification team. After you submit it, our certification team will reach out to you.